# Serial port in VBA without MSComm

Tags: vba, excel

I need to read and write byte arrays using COM-port and VBA. 
I found a nice solution [here](http://dev.emcelettronica.com/serial-port-communication-in-excel-vba)

But this solution works only for String type for input/output data. I need a byte array. I tried to write new functions but I don't know how to accurately read this data. Can you help me?

Comment: did you try using StrConv and different methods of byte array to string conversion?

Comment: @A.S.H I can convert byte to string but microcontroller can't understand string type of data.

Comment: This is a difficult Task, (which i would have preferred doing in C++ since you are using the same APIs). But the idea here is to prepare your Byte Array for the micro-controller, convert it to string, and use the APIs to send the commands. I guess you tried that...

Answer (score 0):

You can sending an array in this way:

```
Dim bWrite(1 To 3) As Byte    
bWrite(1) = &HA1   
bWrite(2) = &HB2    
bWrite(3) = &HC3
       
Dim wr As Long
rc = WriteFile(h, bWrite(1), 3, wr, 0) 'wr indicates how many bytes went to the port.
```

Example from here: https://strokescribe.com/en/serial-port-vb-winapi.html